# How to check if event handlers are already binded to an element?

Tags: bind, jquery

I am using jQuery to bind event handlers to elements, but maybe there is also a way to check using normal JavaScript as well...

If I am using some code like shown below, is there a way to test if the elements already have event handlers added?  When I run the function again (to update an img src), then events are binded a second time, and then the next time a third time, etc.  What is the easiest way?

```
$(window["tdImg_"+i]).add(window["tdImgSize_"+i]).bind('click', toggleImageSize);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to `unbind` the event and re-`bind` it again:

```
$(window["tdImg_"+i]).add(window["tdImgSize_"+i]).unbind('click').bind('click', toggleImageSize);
```

Otherwise, you'd have to access the `events` data, using `$(el).data("events")`, and manually detect if the event was already bound. Also note that this approach excludes `inline` event handlers.

Comment: Don't forget that you can namespace event handlers (http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) - a mechanism provided specifically to avoid clobbering any `click` handlers set outside your code when unbinding your own events. That should make inspecting `.data("events")` unnecessary.

Comment: .data( "events" ) was an undocumented interface that was removed in 1.8 ( http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10589 ).  You can still access it via $._data(element, "events"), but you shouldn't depend on this for any kind of production code

Comment: Great, it works, and seems very easy, and without making an error if there is "nothing to unbind" in the first place, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution:

```
$(window["tdImg_"+i]).each(function(){
    if(!this.boundToggleImageSize){
        $(this).bind('click', toggleImageSize);
        this.boundToggleImageSize = true;
    }
});
```

That way, you don't have to unbind all click events (if you have different bound functions on the same elements).

**EDIT**

As suggested by [**millimoose**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41655/millimoose) in the comments:

```
$(window["tdImg_"+i]).each(function(){
    if(!$(this).data("boundToggleImageSize")){
        $(this).bind('click', toggleImageSize);
        $(this).data("boundToggleImageSize",true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd use `.data()` instead of a property of the DOM element. Also, "bound", not "binded". (Sorry, pet peeve.)

Comment: Both points given! English isn't my native language, so thank you! :-)

Comment: These are also great help, thank you...I am learning a lot.  Glad I found this site, and it's also quite fun to use too.  And now I have 15 points so I can upvote your helpful answers!  Thanks.  :)